# Vue init + Firebase init created nested npm packages

Tags: firebase, vue.js, npm, webpack, vue-cli

I first created a project using Vue CLI, which generated `package.json` and set up the `node_modules` and what not. After that, I used `firebase init` to start a project in the same folder, and chose `functions` as something I wanted to use.

Running this created a folder called `functions` inside my Vue project, which is already scaffold'ed with Vue CLI, so now the folder looks like this:

```
my-project/
  node_modules/
  dist/
  functions/
    node_modules/
    package.json
    index.js
  public/
  src/
  package.json
  index.js
```

Is this normal? Am I not supposed to have two nested packages? If there isn't a clear rule, what's the general/best practice?

If I am supposed to have only one, how do I merge them? Would it be easier to just restart the project folder? (I should note I haven't written any lines of code yet).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There isn't anything necessarily wrong with this setup, nested npm projects aren't uncommon. Assuming you're only using firebase functions, the firebase project and vue project can function independently and thus can live in different npm projects. However, if you're also using the firebase js client in the vue project, you may want to consider merging them.

Comment: I wish you wrote that as a a response instead of comment so I can select it as answer.

Comment: I'll do just that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything necessarily wrong with this setup, nested npm projects aren't uncommon. Assuming you're only using firebase functions, the firebase project and vue project can function independently and thus can live in different npm projects. However, if you're also using the firebase js client in the vue project, you may want to consider merging them.